Spanning set of support functionals in dual space
I am currently studying about supporting hyperplane (or, support functional) in dual space. Since, I am new in these topics I met with the following queries:
Let $X$ be a normed space and $X^*$ be the dual of $X$. Let $z\in S_X$. We define the collection of support functionals at $z$ as
$$J(z)=\{f\in S_{X^*}: f(z)=\|f\|=1\},$$
which is non-empty (by Hahn-Banach theorem) weak star compact (by Banach Alaoglu theorem) convex subset of $S_{X^*}=\{f\in X^*:\|f\|=1\}$. Now my questions are:

What will be the definition of $\text{span}(J(z))$? I think it will look like
$$\text{span}(J(z))=\left\{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_if_i: \lambda_i\in\mathbb{F}, f_i\in J(z), k\in \mathbb{N}\right\},$$
where $\mathbb{F}$ is the scalar field, $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of natural numbers. Is the above definition right?

Is the $\text{span}(J(z))$ is a weak star closed subspace of $X^*$, where $X$ is a normed space? I think it is true when the dimension of $X$ is finite. But if the dimension of $X$ is infinite then what can we say about the subspace $\text{span}(J(z))$? Can anyone give an insight about its closedness in weak star topology? Is the space $X$ has to be a Banach space?


Any kind of help will be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

You got the right answer for the first question. Span works for any set.

Thank you @Captuna. Is the span always a collection of finite linear combinations?

When $X$ is smooth, $J(z)$ is a singleton so that its span is one dimensional and thus (weak-star) closed. I am not sure if it is true in general. I would look at the cases where $X=C(K), L_1, L_\infty$ for a counter-example

@tuntun You're right. Span is always a collection finite linear combinations.

Any finite dimensional normed space is complete. Any subspace is closed.

@HyperbolicPDEfriend Yes for finite dimensional normed space it is ok. What about infinite dimensional normed space?

Could you define $S_{X^*}$? I have never seen that notation before...

@HyperbolicPDEfriend see I have edited for you.
